# FastAPI websockets + PyTest - how to test if a connection was closed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, pytest, fastapi

I'm writing the backend mechanics for an internet game using **FastAPI** websockets for communication between client and server. For testing the framework, I chose **PyTest**. My goal is to write a test which checks the connection was closed.

Not going deeply into implementation, after trying to connect to non-existing room, this should immediately close the connection (the manager does not allow to connect to something which does not exist).

I have completely no idea how to test that. I tried to find any solution using the official documentation but I have found nothing.

Here is my code for testing:

```py
import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from fastapi.websockets import WebSocketDisconnect

from src.game_manager import GameManager
from src.main import app

async def override_manager() -> GameManager:
    try:
        yield override_manager.manager
    except AttributeError:
        manager = GameManager()
        manager.add_new_game(max_players=2, room_name="foo", password=None)
        manager.add_new_game(max_players=2, room_name="bar", password="123")
        override_manager.manager = manager
        yield override_manager.manager


app.dependency_overrides[get_manager] = override_manager

client = TestClient(app)


class TestWebsocketConnection:
    def test_connect_to_non_existing_room(self):
        with pytest.raises(WebSocketDisconnect) as e_info:
            with client.websocket_connect("/ws/non_existing_room") as ws:
                ws.send_json({"message": "Hello world"})
```

This returns

```
FAILED tests/test_websockets.py::TestWebsocketConnection::test_connect_to_non_existing_room - Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'starlette.websockets.WebSocketDisconnect'>
```

And the endpoints look like:

```py
@router.websocket("/ws/{room_name}")
@router.websocket("/ws/{room_name}/{password}")
async def websocket_endpoint(
    websocket: WebSocket,
    manager: Annotated[GameManager, Depends(get_manager)],
):
    room_name = websocket.path_params["room_name"]
    password = websocket.path_params.get("password", None)

    try:
        await manager.connect(websocket, room_name, password)
        client_id = websocket.scope["client_id"]
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_json()
            await manager.handle_message(room_name, client_id, data)
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        await manager.remove(websocket)
```

**NOTE:** `manager.connect(websocket, room_name, password)` raises **WebSocketDisconnect** if a connection should not be allowed.

I would be very grateful if you help me how to test if the connection was closed.

Comment: Do you mean that you expect that `websocket_endpoint` should raise `WebSocketDisconnect`?

Comment: Hi! That was just my unsuccessful try. I mean not fetching `WebSocketDisconnect`, but check if variable `ws` has closed connection.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution.

Provided no JSONs are sent by the websocket after calling `websocket.accept()` and the connection under specific conditions is terminated (`websocket.close()`), we could try to fetch a JSON using `ws.receive_json()`. This should raise `WebSocketDisconnect`.

Here is a working test for anyone having the similar problem like me:

```py
import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from fastapi.websockets import WebSocketDisconnect

...
client = TestClient(app)


class TestWebsocketConnection:
    def test_connect_to_non_existing_room(self):
        with pytest.raises(WebSocketDisconnect):
            with client.websocket_connect("/ws/non_existing_room") as ws:
                ws.receive_json()
```